# drop both row and column satisfying condition in symmetric dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, tidyverse

## Setting

My task looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383376/selecting-by-both-rows-and-columns-in-a-symmetrical-matrix-in-r) but not quite. Suppose I have a symmetric data frame looking like this

```
df <- data.frame(
    matrix(c(1, 7, 0, 5, 9, 0,
             7, 4, 0, 8, 2, 0, 
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
             5, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
             9, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow=6, ncol=6)
)
```

It looks like this

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  1  7  0  5  9  0
2  7  4  0  8  2  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  5  8  0  1  1  0
5  9  2  0  1  1  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Because it's symmetric if a row is full of zeros, the corresponding column with the same index will also be full of zeros.

## What I want to do

I want to drop all the rows and the columns that contain only zero (in general, I would like to drop all the rows and columns satisfying some condition). Ideally, I would like to use functions within the tidyverse. Would be great if I could use pipes somehow.

Is it possible to do this with pipes?

## Important

I made a mistake, I think it's essential that the solution works for sparse matrices. Would it please be possible to have an implementation that works for `dgCMatrix` class? I.e. for sparse matrices?

When I try many of the tidyverse implementations below I get

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('dgCMatrix', 'CsparseMatrix', 'dsparseMatrix', 'generalMatrix', 'dCsparseMatrix', 'dMatrix', 'sparseMatrix', 'compMatrix', 'Matrix', 'xMatrix', 'mMatrix', 'Mnumeric', 'replValueSp')"
```

Comment: A base R option is `Filter(var, subset(df, rowSums(df!=0) > 0))`

Comment: @akrun I will post a separate question cause I made a mistake. I need this to work for a sparse matrix. Would you be able to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 select_if(~ any(. != 0)) %>%
 filter_all(any_vars(. != 0))

  X1 X2 X4 X5
1  1  7  5  9
2  7  4  8  2
3  5  8  1  1
4  9  2  1  1
```

Comment: what does `~` do?

Comment: I'm so confused, all of these functions seem to operate on `variables`, so on columns, yet they filter out rows?

Comment: It is called the tilde operator. Look at `help("~")` and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html. The `select()` family of functions operates on column level, while the `filter()` family operates on rows. So in this case, it first removes the columns where all values are zero and then removes all the rows where all values are zero.

Comment: how comes you use `any_vars` rather than 'all_vars` in the `filter_all` though?

Comment: Also, would you be able to have a similar solution for sparse matrices? I get `Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('dgCMatrix', 'CsparseMatrix', 'dsparseMatrix', 'generalMatrix', 'dCsparseMatrix', 'dMatrix', 'sparseMatrix', 'compMatrix', 'Matrix', 'xMatrix', 'mMatrix', 'Mnumeric', 'replValueSp')"`

Comment: One of the parameters in `filter_all()` is `.vars_predicate`, which should be `A quoted predicate expression as returned by all_vars() or any_vars().`. `dplyr` is essentially not a choice for matrices.

Comment: Then I should definitely rephrase the question

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question (regarding matrices) as there are already answers for this question.

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to combine `dplyr` and `purrr` packages from `tidyverse`

```
df %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(. != 0)) %>%
  purrr::keep(~all((.x != 0)))

  X1 X2 X4 X5
1  1  7  5  9
2  7  4  8  2
3  5  8  1  1
4  9  2  1  1
```

or with `Base R` by checking the standard deviation (`sd`) for every row and column as `sd` for a constant is 0.

```
df[apply(df, 1, sd) != 0, apply(df, 2, sd) != 0]

  X1 X2 X4 X5
1  1  7  5  9
2  7  4  8  2
4  5  8  1  1
5  9  2  1  1
```

Comment: I've never seen `filter_all`, is not even in the cheatsheet!

Comment: What's the difference between `filter_all` and `filter` then?

Comment: Here's the link for `filter_all` command: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter_all.html

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do

```
Filter(var, subset(df, rowSums(df!=0) > 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this for dataframes.

A base R option with `rowSums` and `colSums` can be

```
df[rowSums(df == 0) != ncol(df), colSums(df == 0) != nrow(df)]

#  X1 X2 X4 X5
#1  1  7  5  9
#2  7  4  8  2
#4  5  8  1  1
#5  9  2  1  1
```